# How to find how many words are in one single line of my mobile screen in android jetpack compose

Tags: android, kotlin, text, android-jetpack-compose

I have a very long string and I was displaying it in Text. That is multiline text I want to find how many words are in one single line.

Comment: Try myLongText.split(" ").count()

Comment: @Collaxd this returns the list of words on my string. I want to know how many words are fit in my mobile screen one line.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `onTextLayout` for getting all the `Text` related Infomation.

Here are the steps to get the word count by line in `Text`.

**Explanation**

1. Get Line Count
2. Loop through it
3. Get Line End and extract that string
4. Count the word from the extracted line

Code

```
@Composable
fun Stack018() {
    val textToDraw =
        "Lorem ipsum is placeholder text commonly used in the graphic, print, and publishing industries for previewing layouts and visual mockups"
    
    Text(text = textToDraw,
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        onTextLayout = { textLayoutResult ->
            val lineCount = textLayoutResult.lineCount
            var lineOffset = 0
            for (i in 0 until lineCount ) {
                val lineEndIndex = textLayoutResult.getLineEnd(
                    lineIndex = i,
                    visibleEnd = true
                )
                val lineContent = textToDraw
                    .substring(lineOffset,lineEndIndex)
                Log.e(TAG,"=== Word Count $i= ${lineContent.split(" ").count()}")
                lineOffset = lineEndIndex
            }
        })
}
```

Comment: Hello @chirag it's possible to get the line height?

Comment: Yes You could get height of line

Comment: How can i get ?